# What is the two word answer?

Tags: word

I can be a number

> Take away one, it is the same number
>
> Take away two, it is the same number
>
> Take away three it is another number
>
> Take away four, back to the original number
>
> Take away five, it is the same number

What am I?

Comment: A broken calculator. Haha jk

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I can be a number. What am I?

> You are **NOT ONE**, that is zero.

Take away one, it is the same number

> **NO-ONE**, that is zero persons.

Take away two, it is the same number

> **NONE**

Take away three it is another number

> **ONE**

Take away four, back to the original number

> **NO** (as in "I have no/not one ...")

Take away five, it is the same number

> **O** or oh, looks like a zero and is used for zero when spelling e.g. phone numbers.

Comment: Rot13: Gnxr njnl 4: BB qbhoyr mreb vf nyfb mreb. Og V yvxr lbhe ybtvp gbb. Bravo.